# Typing the store inside the component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, pinia

How can I type the defined store inside a component? I'm getting the error in this template's line: `{{ storeForm.lastName }}` saying "Property 'storeForm' does not exist on type". So I assume I'd need to type the defined store in the code? The store is simple - just a string for the firstName and LastName.

```
<template>
  <v-sheet width="300" class="mx-auto">
      <v-form fast-fail @submit.prevent>
        <v-text-field
          label="First name"
          :rules="firstNameRules"
          placeholder="Your Name"
        >{{ storeForm.firstName }}</v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
          label="Last name"
          :rules="lastNameRules"
        >{{ storeForm.lastName }}</v-text-field>
  
        <v-btn type="submit" block class="mt-2" @click="submit($event)">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-sheet>
  </template>
<script lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import {useForm} from '@/stores/form'
  import  router  from '../router'
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'



  export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const storeForm = useForm();
    const firstName = ref<string>('')
    const lastName = ref<string>('')
    const firstNameRules = ref<any>(
      (value: String)  => {
        if (value?.length > 3) return true
        return 'First name must be at least 3 characters.'
      }
    )
    const lastNameRules = ref<any>(
      (value: String) => {
          if (/[^0-9]/.test(String(value))) return true
          return 'Last name can not contain digits.'
        }
        )
        
        const submit = (event: Event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          let user = {
            firstName: firstName.value,
            lastName: lastName.value,
          }
          storeForm.login(user)
          
          router.push('/');
          
          firstName.value = '';
          lastName.value = '';
        }
        return {firstName, lastName, firstNameRules, lastNameRules, submit};
  }
})
</script>
```

**stores/form.ts**

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useForm = defineStore(
  {
  id: 'login',
  state: () => ({
    firstName: <string>'',
    lastName: <string>''
  }),
  actions: {
    login(data: any) {
      this.firstName = data.firstName
      this.lastName = data.lastName
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please add the "useForm" code as well.

Comment: I've posted the UseForm store code also, appreciate

Comment: the entire error looks like this - Property 'storeForm' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch<T extends string | ((...args: any) => any)>(source: T, cb: T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? (args_0: R, args_1: R) => ...'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should honestly be running into a lot more errors than just an "undefined" error. For one, Pinia should be complaining that it's broken. The reason is because your script code is an incorrect mix of Vue 2's Options API (using `methods` object) and Vue 3's Composition API (using `setup` function).  You need to pick and stick with one API syntax.  Since you're using Vue 3 with refs, Composition API seems to be the better choice.  The line in question `const storeForm = useForm()` doesn't conform to either API but when going with Composition API it should be inside `setup()`

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useForm } from '@/stores/form';

export default {
  setup() {
    const storeForm = useForm();
    const firstName = ref<string>('');
    const lastName = ref<string>('');

    const submit = (event: any) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const user = {
        firstName: firstName.value,
        lastName: lastName.value
      };

      storeForm.login(user);

      firstName.value = '';
      lastName.value = '';
    };
    return { firstName, lastName, submit };
  }
};
</script>
```

I highly suggest reviewing the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles) as it's an excellent learning tool. Make sure to understand the differences between Options API and Composition API and how to properly create a component, specifically with Composition API.  Most documentation for Composition API will actually use the `script setup` syntax which is a bit simpler compared to using the `setup()` function and would make your script code look like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useForm } from '@/stores/form';

const storeForm = useForm();
const firstName = ref<string>('');
const lastName = ref<string>('');

const submit = (event: any) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const user = {
    firstName: firstName.value,
    lastName: lastName.value
  };

  storeForm.login(user);

  firstName.value = '';
  lastName.value = '';
};
</script>
```

Comment: THX al lot! I changed that lines of the code, but the Type error "StoreFront does not exist on type" in this line - {{ storeForm.lastName }} - hadn't disappeared

Comment: Is the error reported by your IDE or in your browser's console? Can you copy/paste the full error? Even a screenshot will do if it's from your IDE.  I've now ran the exact same code received no errors.

Comment: The error is in IDE (VSC), and the error looks like this - Property 'storeForm' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch<T extends string | ((...args: any) => any)>(source: T, cb: T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? (args_0: R, args_1: R) => ...'.ts(2339)